# Dynamically create Spring beans that extend an abstract class with parameterized types

Tags: java, spring, generics

I would like to take advantage of Spring 4.0's support for autowiring of generic types but I would like to avoid having to create explicit concrete or anonymous classes for each type.  To use an example, lets say I have an interface:

```
public interface Cache<T extends Entity>
```

And an abstract implementation of the interface:

```
public abstract class AbstractCache<T extends Entity> implements Cache<T>
{
    @Autowired
    private EntityDao<T> dao;

    @Autowired
    private List<CacheListener<T>> listeners;
    ...
}
```

And entity classes A to Z that implement Entity (e.g):

```
public class A implements Entity
public class B implements Entity
...
public class Z implements Entity
```

Is there a way I can create instances of `Cache<A>` through `Cache<Z>` such that I can autowire these generic types in other classes?  E.g.

```
@Autowire
private Cache<Z> zCache;
```

I know I can achieve this by individually defining each bean, E.g.

```
@Bean
public Cache<Z> cacheZ() {
    return new AbstractCache<Z> () {};
}
```

But I have been unable to come up with a way to do this for all Entity classes in a particular package.  E.g.

```
public void registerEntityCaches (BeanFactory beanFactory) {
    for (Class<? extends Entity> cls : entityPackage.getAllClasses()) {
         beanFactory.registerBean(new AbstractCache<cls>() {});
    }
}
```

Is something like this possible or do I have to define them individually?